# AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to write a script that tells me the number of unread emails.
But I'm getting AttributeError.

My Code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class email:
    def unread():
        url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox'
        headers_A = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
        site = requests.get(url, headers=headers_A)
        info = BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')
        unread = info.find('div', attrs={'class', 'bsU'}).text
        return unread

email = email()
unread = email.unread()
print(unread)
```

The error code

```py
AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'client'
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need to add `.content` to `site` in `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem with a webscraper is an obvious idea because you would normally check your email through a browser.

Yet, to make a webscraper like this takes more than just one HTTP `get` request to the url for the inbox.

You would need to go through googles online authentication which is quite complicated as far as I know, then you would need to manage the session and cookies to stay logged in when you do your scraping.

Actually there is a much easier way to solve this problem.

In webscraping you are using the HTTP protocol, but when emailing, another protocol is used which much simpler and totally independent of HTTP. it's IMAP.

This means you don't need to use `bs4` or `requests`, you can just connect to Googles IMAP server.

[Here is a tutorial which will explain you how you can make a simple python IMAP client.](https://codehandbook.org/how-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-python/)

You will also need to allow less secure apps on your google account for this to work. [You can do that here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)